# What's the stock way of learning APIs for Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

So there are a ton of dart packages that do all the heavy lifting regarding API handling but I am looking for the ground-up approach to learning API's and how they are handled within the Flutter framework. Wondering if there are any sources/tutorials on how to do so. With the exception of google's own documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the official website to handle APIs in flutter-

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

and here's a good documentation of basic flow of API integration-

https://mobikul.com/http-api-calling-in-flutter/

Hope it will work for you.